# how can I connect to mariadb galera from python

Tags: python, mariadb, galera

Is there any way of connecting to a MariaDB Galera cluster from python 2.7 ?

I have a two node cluster and found out that a conector for java exists.

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Comment: Research how to connect python to MySQL.  That will give you the basic answer.  If you need to ask about load balance between the Galera Nodes, so specify.

Comment: I have investigated the master-slave cenário. With that setup I can use the normal mysql python conector. But with galera I am not so shure about the way to connect.